# Heroku logging and exception tracking

Tags: heroku, rsyslog, airbrake

I'm been playing around with Heroku, Airbrake and Papertrail. I love the Airbrake interface and exception tracking system. It's one crippling weakness is that you have to send messages to it synchronously. Ouch! Wouldn't it be great if you could point your Heroku rsyslog to a service like Papertrail, and have Papertrail detect Airbrake XML messages and post them to your Airbrake/errbit server?

Has anyone ever done anything like this?

If not, what would people recommend to make sending data to Airbrake asynchronous?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now asynchronous.

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Using-Airbrake-asynchronously

Stu

Answer (score 4):

There is currently a ticket open to make Airbrake Asynchronous , https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/69. I'll post here once it's updated.

Ben